# Error while using react-native-svg library on react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to use svg images in place of png icons because the quality of icons rendered by png is not good.I have folloing specifications

```
"react-native": "^0.42.3",
"react-native-svg": "4.3.0",
"react": "^15.4.1"
```

After "npm install" ,When I import react-native-svg in my project, it throws following errors

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-svg/lib/SvgTouchableMixin.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Components/Touchable/Touchable' in '/home/payalverma/Projects/caro-mobile/node_modules/react-native-svg/lib'
@ ./node_modules/react-native-svg/lib/SvgTouchableMixin.js 1:296-360
@ ./node_modules/react-native-svg/elements/Shape.js
@ ./node_modules/react-native-svg/elements/Rect.js
@ ./node_modules/react-native-svg/index.js
@ ./app/components/common/DrawerContent.js
@ ./app/components/Home.js
@ ./app/components/routes/Navigation.web.js
@ ./app/index.js
@ ./index.web.js
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:5000 webpack/hot/dev-server ./index.web.js
```

Anyone has similar issues or can help me with he same.any missing dependencies that needs to be installed?

Comment: Can you please add the code for the import statement please.

Comment: I have a library named react-native-svg-uri(https://github.com/matc4/react-native-svg-uri ) which uses react-native-svg  as its dependency. So following is my import code  : import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri'; and it is throwing above mentioned error

Comment: did you run `react-native link react-native-svg` after you installed like the documentation says?

Comment: yes. Is this problem related to versions I am using?

Comment: I have used this import as well and it is throwing same error :  import Svg,{
  Circle,
  Ellipse,
  G,
  LinearGradient,
  RadialGradient,
  Line,
  Path,
  Polygon,
  Polyline,
  Rect,
  Symbol,
  Use,
  Defs,
  Stop
} from 'react-native-svg';

Answer (score 1):

Actually react-native-svg do not include react-native-web in the dependency.
However it is included in "/node_modules/react-native-svg/index.web.js".

Just run this command

```
npm i react-native-web
```

Error will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

You have to

```
yarn add react-native-web react-dom
```

According to these docs
https://docs.expo.io/guides/running-in-the-browser/